# Instagram sdk in own app

Tags: ios, instagram

I have public account in Instagram and I want that people that downloaded my app can post photo from that account.

How can I achieve this???

I know how to post photo if I login in Instagram but if user login from his account he will post image to his wall. Thank's for help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Instagram API does not support the creation of new posts.

Comment: @user24073 i can post image to instagram. But i want to know if it is possible to post image in my app from 1 account

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't post photo from other account. but you can find all information about posting photos on this page
[iPhone-hooks](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/):

Answer (score 0):

```
            Steps For Instagram Authentication

1] Authentication in    https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ 


2] Add Plist File

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
        </dict>
<key>InstagramAppClientId</key>
    <string>7fa58b530dad4fe0a6cd63e2b261f0b9</string>
    <key>InstagramAppRedirectURL</key>
    <string>http://agileinfways.com</string>

3] Pod File Setup like,

     1) Open Command Prompt
     2) Go to Folder Directory
     3) pod setup
     4) pod init
     5) touch podfile
     6) OPEN -e podfile
     7) This  Pod File Add this line like,

    target 'App Name' do
        pod 'InstagramKit', '~> 3.6'
    end

    8) pod install
    9)Then Open Appname.xcworkspace File.
```